# kill matlab process in task manager using python

Tags: python, matlab, process

Every now and then, I run into this problem:
my python script calls matlab, runs a simulation and closes matlab. Sometimes, matlab does not close properly.
then, i run batch script that builds Visual studio dll/lib , which unfortunately are held up by matlab.

Is there a way to find process id for Matlab using python and then kill it.
I can then add this to end of my python script to safely close matlab.
Thanks
sedy

Comment: How do you call Matlab from python?  I use bash or ksh and I call it like this: `matlab_2015a -r "<function with arguments>;exit;"`.  This has never failed to close Matlab.  Are you working with files that could still be open?

Comment: well, I am on win 7 and use something like _"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\matlab.exe" -nosplash -nodesktop -wait -logfile LogFile.log -minimize -r  Mat_func"_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To kill all processes containing "matlab" in its name you can use

```
import os
import psutil

allMatlabIds = [p.pid for p in psutil.process_iter() if "matlab" in str(p.name)]
MatlabIdsToKill = [x for x in allMatlabIds if x != os.getpid()]
for MatlabId in MatlabIdsToKill:
    os.kill(MatlabId, signal.SIGINT)
```